# Error 400 in my function but i dont' understand why

Tags: javascript

I have created a function `getLoginSessions` that returns an array. I have an `addGetRoute('sessions', 'getLoginSessions()')` in a controller. Now i have a form where I would like print last 10 access (calculated by function `getLoginSessions()` and returned in to array).

```
function sessions(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/hm-api/login/sessions',
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            csrf_token: $("#csrf_token").val(),
        },
        success: function (rep) {
            console.log(rep);
            //success
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

But the console return an error: error 400.

Comment: `HTTP 400` indicates client side error. Can you please share more detail from the error message?

Comment: Error 400 is bad request, that means you are missing something to send something in API

Comment: In your browser, you can check out the network tab what gets sent to the server. It might expect a different `content-type` header for the data you are sending or something like that.

Comment: the error is "status": 400,↵    "error": "RouteNotFoundException",↵    "message": "There is no route for 'sessions'."